# possible to retrieve encryption passwords from PDF using iText?

Tags: pdf, itext

I would like to define a small set of passwords to be used between two systems that collaborate on PDFs.  Applying the hashed value from /U or /O I would like to select the appropriate password.  Does iTextPDF expose the ability to access the hashed passwords?

Comment: What exactly do you want to retrieve? The **U** and **O** values? Clear text passwords? Something else?

Comment: If you already know the passwords cycle each one until it works, you'll get an exception if the password is wrong.